# Facebook Live Stream Box HTTPS

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, facebook-widgets

I have page with HTTPS and I need to use Live Stream Box on it . I used iFrame (code below) . But when user loges in it the popup goes to after login http://www.facebook.com/popup_closer.php which users http so has permission issue as I use https in iframe src.

If I use same think with http it works but fine in FF and Chrome but IE gets issue with http shown under HTTPS .How do I get this working ?

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/live_stream_box.php?always_post_to_friends=false&height=600&width=490&xid=1&app_id={my_app_id}" width="490" height="600" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

Really need a help in this matter .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that its a bug with facebook .

Submitted a bug here http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=17422